# Type Mismatch VBA when pasting data into multiple Cells and using Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a drop-down List in cells `G3:G102` where you can choose a value from 1 to 50. By choosing a number from the list, the next three columns are populated with VBA with things such as:

```
1.
2.
3.
```

and

```
On floor 1: ?
On floor 2: ?
On floor 3: ?
```

So I have this VBA code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("G3:G102")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' If any one of these cells in the range KeyCells has been modified, then retrieve its value
        floorValue = Range(Target.Address)

        ' Here is the loop I use it will loop X-amount of times based on the number from 'KeyCells'
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 1 To Range(Target.Address).Value
        ' myText and myText2 are two variables that I am populating here with multiple lines.
            myText = myText & i & "." & vbNewLine
            myText2 = myText2 & "On floor " & i & ": ?" & vbNewLine
        Next i


        'Then insert that data into the cells to the right
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = myText
        Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = myText2
        Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = myText2


    End If
End Sub
```

**The issue I have**

If I paste into multiple cells at the same time or shift-drag data into multiple cells at the same time, I will get a `Type mismatch` error, specifically at this point:
`For i = 1 To Range(Target.Address).Value`

Comment: You have to loop through each cell in Target. Btw `Range(Target.Address)` is the same as `Target`.

Comment: How are you confirming `Target` is only one cell and not multiple cells?

Comment: I am not confirming it, and I understand this is where the issue comes from. I don't know how I would circumvent it.

Comment: I originally thought that the VBA would work its thing one cell at a time, not multiple.

Comment: Simple code is `Dim cel as Range` then `For Each cel in Target`.

Comment: you could also exclude multi-cell ranges with `if target.count>1 then exit sub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, ultimately, something like this is what you're looking for:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim KeyCell As Range
    Dim floorValue As Long
    Dim myText As String
    Dim myText2 As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set KeyCells = Intersect(Me.Range("G3:G102"), Target)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not KeyCells Is Nothing Then
        For Each KeyCell In KeyCells.Cells
            myText = vbNullString
            myText2 = vbNullString

            ' If any one of these cells in the range KeyCells has been modified, then retrieve its value
            floorValue = KeyCell.Value

            ' Here is the loop I use it will loop X-amount of times based on the number from 'KeyCells'
            For i = 1 To floorValue
                'myText and myText2 are two variables that I am populating here with multiple lines.
                myText = myText & i & "." & vbNewLine
                myText2 = myText2 & "On floor " & i & ": ?" & vbNewLine
            Next i

            'Then insert that data into the cells to the right
            KeyCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = myText
            KeyCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = myText2
            KeyCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = myText2
        Next KeyCell
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I was about to edit my answer to something more like this and I realized that the `For i - 1` loop is not needed, its replacing the strings each time, why not just take the value in `floorValue`?

Comment: @RicardoA It's not actually replacing the strings, it's building the strings with new lines for 1 to x.  So it would end up being all of this in a single cell for example: `On floor 1: ?<vbNewLine>On floor 2: ?`

Comment: Wow, this is the first code that works. There is still a bug though where if I drag down a value such as `3` to multiple cells below - I will eventually get results like `1 2 3 1 2 3` and below that `1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3` and so on.

Comment: @pufAmuf I realized that bug as I posted it.  I have edited the code to correct.  Refresh the page and try again please.

Comment: @tigeravatar true, got confused at the first glance.

Answer (score 0):

Loop each cell in the range when pasting multiple values. This should fix it, not tested.

```
    Dim rng as Range
    For each rng in Range(Target.Address)
        'myText and myText2 are two variables that I am populating here with multiple lines.
        myText = myText & rng.value & "." & vbNewLine
        myText2 = myText2 & "On floor " & rng.value & ": ?" & vbNewLine
        rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = myText
        rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = myText2
        rng.Offset(0, 3).Value = myText2
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks - however Excel does not like `Next i` at the bottom (Invalid Next control variable reference)

Comment: remove the `i` i forgot about it, just leave it at Next

Comment: Great, no errors now. However there is no loop happening. If I choose `5` from the dropdown list, what is produced is `On floor 5: ?`, instead of 5 lines like before.

Comment: I just tried it, but it will still produce only 1 line, no matter what number I choose.

Comment: After reading the other answer I realized the outcome you were looking for. This only does 1 line per range. The answer from tigeravatar is the correct one.

Comment: No problem, thank you for all your time and effort Ricardo